# App crashes when a button is pressed used for checking user answer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, findviewbyid

Hello I am trying to create a simple number guesser app where if the number guessed by the user matches with the Random number generator, the textView should output "you have correctly guessed the number" or not but whenever I press the button the program crashes. Please help

The program crashes whenever I press the button.The user should input their number in userAns variable and if the answer is correct. answerCorrect variable should be executed and the text should be displayed and if the number guessed by the user is wrong. answerWrong variable should be executed. I am a beginner so please help

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //Calling button method
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.guessBtn)
        //Set on click listener for the button
        button.setOnClickListener {
            buttonPressed()
          }
         }
        //Creating button for button pressed
        private fun buttonPressed() {
            //Method to find view from activity_main
            val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)
            val userAns = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer).toString().toInt()
            //This variable will display the answer
            val answerCorrect = "Congrats, you have correctly guessed the number"
            val answerWrong = "Sorry,you have guessed the wrong number"
            //Making random numbers from 1 to 10
            var randomValues = Random.nextInt(1, 10)
            //Adding a condition to check if user answer matches the random answer
            if(userAns == randomValues){
                result.text = answerCorrect
            }
            else{
                result.text = answerWrong
            }

             }
             }
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace so we can understand where it is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the stack trace, I think I can guess where the crash is occurring from.

You have the following line inside your **buttonPressed** method:

```
    val userAns = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer).toString().toInt()
```

Here you are accessing a view which is an EditText and trying to convert it to a string and then to an integer.

I think what you mean to do is get the value from your EditText and then convert that to an Integer.

You can achieve that by doing this:

```
 val userAnsEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)
 val userAnsText = userAnsEditText.text.toString()
 val userAnsInt = userAnsText.toInt()
```

This is assuming that you are using the correct id for the EditText.

Comment: Wow thank you so much this helped my program. And is there any reason why I cant change to Int from String in the same line?

Comment: @Blinky - No reason, you can do it on one line. I just wanted to break down the steps so it is as clear as possible to you.

Comment: Ahh i see thank you very much brother

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here :

```
val userAns = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer).toString().toInt()
```

You get the `EditText` by findViewById, you should get text from it and then store it in your variable

```
val userAns = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer).text.toString().toInt()
```

NOTE : Whenever the app crashes, the Android Studio will generate a stack trace, which you can see in LogCat window. It usually has the reason for crash as well as the exact line number where the crash happened. You should go through it whenever any crash happens, to debug the issue.